# Changing autoformatting in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I installed Visual Studio **2012**. How can I do disable auto formatting code (C++)?
When I write code, VS puts spaces where it wants. 
If disabling is impossible, how can I change the formatting to:

```
int a = MyFunc();
switch (a)
  {
    default:
      break;
    // ...
  }
```

but studio remaking this:

```
int a = MyFunc();
switch (a)
{
default:
  break;
// ...
}
```

Comment: Try looking at Tools > Options > Text Editor >

Comment: I tried, but did not help. I also tried to change the formatting for C# - without effect :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Tools > Options > Text Editor, then C/C++ > Formatting > Indentation > Indent Braces?

This seems to fix the Braces part.